# How can I add depth with box-shadow in css?

Tags: css

How can I add depth with box-shadow in Css?
Could you please explain to me or suggest a resource.
I found this line of code but i can't understand it.

```
box-shadow: 4px 8px 4px -2px #ccc,  0px 0px 6px -2px #ccc;
```

Comment: What do you call "depth"?

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) to have a better understanding of what the line of code does.

Comment: Does that line of code produce the effect you want? If so, on what shape of element? Could you include a snippet of code and also explain further what your question actually is, otherwise you are in danger of getting answers which just repeat existing documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In

```css
box-shadow: 4px 8px 6px -2px #ccc;
```

`4px` is the x-offset of the shadow

`8px` is the y-offset of the shadow

`6px` is the blur-radius of the shadow

`-2px` is the spread-radius of the shadow

The shape of the box-shadow is related to the shape of the element it is attached to

You can use devtools to help you understand it.

[image: box-shadow]

Read the [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) to have a deeper understanding of it.

Comment: Excellent explanation, @Gerrnperl. This is tangential, but may I ask how you created your animated gif? Many thanks.

Comment: @Rounin-StandingwithUkraine I use [peek](https://github.com/phw/peek) to record my steps on chrome devtool